# How can I remove a specific user from the Ubuntu login screen?

Tags: lightdm, login-screen

I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS. When I login, there is an extra user called 'Oracle' present. How can I hide this?

[image: Illustration of Problem]

Comment: @Terrance Ubuntu used LightDM now, so I don't think that answer would work, as it applies to GDM.

Comment: @Terrance Even if you are using Gnome Desktop, the display manager is still LightDM on Ubuntu. See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM for confirmation. The display manager is separate from the desktop environment. GDM looks very different indeed.

Comment: @jdp407 Nope.  My system has both GDM and LightDM installed.  I switched to GDM and it looks exactly the same.

Comment: @Terrance Ok, I must be mistaken - I was under the impression that the Unity greeter was purely a LightDM theme - can you send me a link to where you can get a copy of the unity greeter for GDM? I prefer it to the stock GDM theme (which I'm using at the moment). Also, if you run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` it will tell you which display manager you are currently running.

Comment: @jdp407 You are correct.  For some reason it didn't take.  It is now GDM fine, but the greeter is different.  Please forgive me.

Comment: @Terrance Don't worry about it - sorry if I came across as rude.

Comment: @jdp407 No problem!  Everything is good.  Somewhere somehow I also got confused between my work system and my home system.  My work system has GDM, but is running LightDM, and my home system only has GDM on it.

Comment: You all are firing in dark, no one is able to answer in a simple way, I have find an easy way to remove a user from login screen, just go to system setting then go to user accounts and click on the user name which you want to remove, so simple and easy.